# Concurrency issue for two back to back request

Tags: java, spring

We have java application(hosted on two nodes) which read from MQ and write record to Database.
In database it is writing person information which has email associated with it. Email should be unique and can be nullable. So this validation is managed at the code level and there no data base constraint. Also we are using Information MDM (master data management tool) and it does not allow to define unique nullable constraint.
The problem we are facing is duplicate records are getting created in if same contact is pushed in MQ back to back.The root cause is as follows
Process 1 pick message 1 and starts processing it find it as Unique and start creating new record.
Process 2 pick message 2 before process 1 is completed so it also find this record as unique.

Both process end up writing to database due to which duplicate record gets created.
Is there any way to manage this?

Comment: The only 100% way is to use a unique constraint else you always will/might run into this. Or lock the whole database, do an update/insert, and unlock. However this is very bad for your performance.

Answer (score 0):

As variant, I can offer a solution to you: **optimistic locking** in db record. It means that in one transaction you shoud do three things:

1. Get actual version of the DB record
2. Update DB record only if version was not changed.
3. Repeate 1 and 2 until success.

Comment: Thank you Oleg we do that but does not solve the problem in hand. Let me give an example. Process 1 checks in DB the record is not present and start writing it meanwhile process 2 also start before process 1 goes to completion so process 2 also think it is new record and they both end writing same stuff.